# Perl - Using backquotes missing output

Tags: perl, stdout, capture

Hello guys i need to capture the output of an external command, herefore I use backquotes.
However when the command reaches a newline the output is ommitted. Where $_ = AD

```
@lines = `"C:/Program Files/Veritas/NetBackup/bin/admincmd/bppllist" $_ -U"`
```

```
Test: test1
Test: test2

Test: test3
Test: test4
```

The actual output:
@lines

```
Test: test1
Test: test2
```

Thank you for your time.

```
    print HTML "<h2 id='pol'>Policy Configuration\n</h2>" ;

  @bpllist =`"$admincmd/bppllist.exe"` or die print "$admincmd/bppllist.exe not found or could not be executed";
foreach (@bpllist) 
{
  print HTML "<div><table class='table'>\n";
  @lines = `"$admincmd/bppllist" $_ -U` or die print       "$admincmd/bpplinfo $_ -U not found or could not be executed";
   print HTML "\t<tr>\n\t<td><b>Policy name: <b></td><td>$_</td>\n\t</tr>\n" ;

  foreach (@lines) {

chop;
 ($var, $value) = split(/:/,$_,2);
 $var = "" if !defined($var);
 $value = "" if !defined($value);
print HTML "\t<tr>\n\t<td>$var</td><td>$value</td>\n\t</tr>\n" ;

  } 
  print HTML "</table></div>";
  }
```

The output of @bpllist:

```
  AD
  Sharepoint
  Echchange
  Vmware
```

Comment: No, not as a comment, `edit` your question above.

Comment: What does `$_` contain? Why haven't you posted a FULL example of what you're trying?

Comment: Please `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Don't combine the `join` with LIST context. Either use `join` and `$output` or just `@output`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to capture the STDOUT & STDERR of a spawned process using backticks:

```
my $output = join('', `command arg1 arg2 arg3 2>&1`);
```

How it works has no dependence whatsoever on newlines in the output of `command`.

If you also need to send text to `command`'s STDIN, then use IPC::Open3.

---

Cleaned your code up a bit. It works for me.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;

# something missing here to set up HTML file handle
# something missing here to set up $admincmd

print HTML q{<h2 id='pol'>Policy Configuration\n</h2>};
my @bpllist = `"$admincmd/bppllist.exe"` 
  or die "$admincmd/bppllist.exe not found or could not be executed\n";
for my $policy (@bpllist) {
  print HTML q{<div><table class='table'>\n};
  my @lines = `$admincmd/bpplinfo.exe $policy -U 2>&1`;
  print HTML qq{\t<tr>\n\t<td><b>Policy name: <b></td><td>$policy</td>\n\t</tr>\n} ;
  for my $pair (@lines) {
    chomp($pair); # only remove newlines, not other characters
    my ($var, $value) = split /:/, $pair, 2;
    $var //= '';
    $value //= '';
    print HTML qq{\t<tr>\n\t<td>$var</td><td>$value</td>\n\t</tr>\n} ;
  }
  print HTML q{</table></div>};
}
```

**Update 2**

You appear to be doing this on windows?

I don't think the `2>&1` trick will work there.

Comment: When I try to do it that way I get: 'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: That command doesn't have backticks - those are double-quotes - did the StackOverflow comment eat them? Also either use $lines (for all lines in a single string), or don't use join().

Comment: Please update your question to contain the REAL code that isn't working for you. Make sure to `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Update your question above. Place for spaces before each line of code and leave a blank line above and below your full code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `qx` or backticks and then shell commands to redirect output, give the core module, [IPC::Cmd](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Cmd.html), a try. In particular, its exportable function `&run` will conveniently capture both STDOUT and STDERR for you. From the synopsis:

```
### in list context ###
my( $success, $error_message, $full_buf, $stdout_buf, $stderr_buf ) =
run( command => $cmd, verbose => 0 );
```

Comment: It looks like @David-SkyMesh else pointed out the cause of that in a comment. At any rate, `&IPC::Cmd::run` won't give you such trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the command send its output to stderr.

Try this:

```
my $output = `'command' -ARG -L 2>&1`;
```

regards,

Comment: That's because `$output = \`blah\`` in SCALAR context is only capturing the first line. You need to do `@output = \`blah\`` in LIST context. The `join()` in my answer forces LIST context.

Comment: Ok did that but the output after the newline is still missing!

Comment: Edit your question again, don't leave out anything!